# how to use result of query(*) to identify textbox and button ,and use performAction and touch to input text and click button

Tags: calabash

I have found through all of topics, but haven't found any answer related with my question.

I test a webview apk.
I open a url("http://m.youdao.com/") and want to enter text into editbox and click research button.

The button has no id and name, see  HTML by view source of the web.

Now query(*) works and output many things , but the question is  which one related with the textbox and which one related with the button. I want to input "test" in textbox and click search button .

result of query :
    irb(main):006:0> query"*"
    [
        [ 0] {
                            "id" => nil,
                       "enabled" => true,
            "contentDescription" => nil,
                         "class" => "com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView",
                          "rect" => {
                "center_y" => 142.0,
                "center_x" => 120.0,
                  "height" => 284,
                       "y" => 0,
                   "width" => 240,
                       "x" => 0
            },
                   "description" => "com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b2da1390 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-240,284}"
        },
        [ 1] {
                            "id" => "action_bar_overlay_layout",
                       "enabled" => true,
            "contentDescription" => nil,
                         "class" => "com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout",
                          "rect" => {
                "center_y" => 142.0,
                "center_x" => 120.0,
                  "height" => 284,
                       "y" => 0,
                   "width" => 240,
                       "x" => 0
            },
                   "description" => "com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout{b2dfed00 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-240,284 #1020313 android:id/action_bar_overlay_layout}"
        },
        [ 2] {
                            "id" => "content",
                       "enabled" => true,
            "contentDescription" => nil,
                         "class" => "android.widget.FrameLayout",
                          "rect" => {
                "center_y" => 169.5,
                "center_x" => 120.0,
                  "height" => 229,
                       "y" => 55,
                   "width" => 240,
                       "x" => 0
            },
                   "description" => "android.widget.FrameLayout{b2da5930 V.E..... ......I. 0,55-240,284 #1020002 android:id/content}"
        },
        [ 3] {
                            "id" => "container",
                       "enabled" => true,
            "contentDescription" => nil,
                         "class" => "android.widget.FrameLayout",
                          "rect" => {
                "center_y" => 169.5,
                "center_x" => 120.0,
                  "height" => 229,
                       "y" => 55,
                   "width" => 240,
                       "x" => 0
            },
                   "description" => "android.widget.FrameLayout{b2df76d0 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-240,229 #7f05003c app:id/container}"
        },
        [ 4] {
                            "id" => nil,
                       "enabled" => true,
            "contentDescription" => nil,
                         "class" => "android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout",
                          "rect" => {
                "center_y" => 169.5,
                "center_x" => 120.0,
                  "height" => 229,
                       "y" => 55,
                   "width" => 240,
                       "x" => 0
            },
                   "description" => "android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout{b2e2c3b8 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-240,229}"
        },
        [ 5] {
                            "id" => nil,
                       "enabled" => true,
            "contentDescription" => nil,
                         "class" => "android.widget.LinearLayout",
                          "rect" => {
                "center_y" => 169.5,
                "center_x" => 120.0,
                  "height" => 229,
                       "y" => 55,
                   "width" => 240,
                       "x" => 0
            },
                   "description" => "android.widget.LinearLayout{b2df86d8 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-240,229}"
        },
        [ 6] {
                            "id" => "mywebview",
                       "enabled" => true,
            "contentDescription" => "Web View",
                         "class" => "android.webkit.WebView",
                          "rect" => {
                "center_y" => 169.5,
                "center_x" => 120.0,
                  "height" => 229,
                       "y" => 55,
                   "width" => 240,
                       "x" => 0
            },
                   "description" => "android.webkit.WebView{b2dbdd18 VFEDHVC. .F....I. 0,0-240,229 #7f05003d app:id/mywebview}"
        },
        [ 7] {
                            "id" => "action_bar_container",
                       "enabled" => true,
            "contentDescription" => nil,
                         "class" => "com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer",
                          "rect" => {
                "center_y" => 37.0,
                "center_x" => 120.0,
                  "height" => 36,
                       "y" => 19,
                   "width" => 240,
                       "x" => 0
            },
                   "description" => "com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{b2dab088 V.ED.... ......I. 0,19-240,55 #1020314 android:id/action_bar_container}"
        },
        [ 8] {
                            "id" => "action_bar",
                       "enabled" => true,
            "contentDescription" => nil,
                         "class" => "com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView",
                          "rect" => {
                "center_y" => 37.0,
                "center_x" => 120.0,
                  "height" => 36,
                       "y" => 19,
                   "width" => 240,
                       "x" => 0
            },
                   "description" => "com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView{b2d98560 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-240,36 #1020315 android:id/action_bar}"
        },
        [ 9] {
                            "id" => nil,
                       "enabled" => false,
            "contentDescription" => nil,
                         "class" => "android.widget.LinearLayout",
                          "rect" => {
                "center_y" => 37.0,
                "center_x" => 66.5,
                  "height" => 36,
                       "y" => 19,
                   "width" => 119,
                       "x" => 7
            },
                   "description" => "android.widget.LinearLayout{b2dab638 V.....C. ......I. 7,0-126,36}"
        },
        [10] {
                            "id" => nil,
                       "enabled" => true,
            "contentDescription" => nil,
                         "class" => "com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView",
                          "rect" => {
                "center_y" => 37.0,
                "center_x" => 22.0,
                  "height" => 36,
                       "y" => 19,
                   "width" => 30,
                       "x" => 7
            },
                   "description" => "com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView{b2de3f00 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-30,36}"
        },
        [11] {
                            "id" => "home",
                       "enabled" => true,
            "contentDescription" => nil,
                         "class" => "android.widget.ImageView",
                          "rect" => {
                "center_y" => 37.0,
                "center_x" => 22.0,
                  "height" => 24,
                       "y" => 25,
                   "width" => 24,
                       "x" => 10
            },
                   "description" => "android.widget.ImageView{b2e14210 V.ED.... ......I. 3,6-27,30 #102002c android:id/home}"
        },
        [12] {
                            "id" => nil,
                       "enabled" => true,
            "contentDescription" => nil,
                         "class" => "android.widget.LinearLayout",
                          "rect" => {
                "center_y" => 36.5,
                "center_x" => 81.5,
                  "height" => 19,
                       "y" => 27,
                   "width" => 89,
                       "x" => 37
            },
                   "description" => "android.widget.LinearLayout{b2dda508 V.E..... ......I. 30,8-119,27}"
        },
        [13] {
                            "id" => "action_bar_title",
                       "enabled" => true,
            "contentDescription" => nil,
                         "class" => "android.widget.TextView",
                          "text" => "TestWebView",
                          "rect" => {
                "center_y" => 36.5,
                "center_x" => 78.5,
                  "height" => 19,
                       "y" => 27,
                   "width" => 83,
                       "x" => 37
            },
                   "description" => "android.widget.TextView{b2dbc4b8 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-83,19 #1020265 android:id/action_bar_title}"
        },
        [14] {
                            "id" => nil,
                       "enabled" => true,
            "contentDescription" => nil,
                         "class" => "com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView",
                          "rect" => {
                "center_y" => 37.0,
                "center_x" => 219.0,
                  "height" => 36,
                       "y" => 19,
                   "width" => 42,
                       "x" => 198
            },
                   "description" => "com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView{b2df5188 V.ED.... ......I. 198,0-240,36}"
        },
        [15] {
                            "id" => nil,
                       "enabled" => true,
            "contentDescription" => "More options",
                         "class" => "com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuPresenter$OverflowMenuButton",
                          "rect" => {
                "center_y" => 37.0,
                "center_x" => 219.0,
                  "height" => 36,
                       "y" => 19,
                   "width" => 42,
                       "x" => 198
            },
                   "description" => "com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuPresenter$OverflowMenuButton{b2de1788 VFED..C. ......I. 0,0-42,36}"
        }
    ]
Here is my feature and step definition.
    Feature: WebView feature

```
  Scenario: Test WebView

    Then I wait for 10 seconds

    Then I take a picture

    Then I enter "test" into input field with id "formInput" 

    Then I wait for 100 seconds

    Then I take a picture

    Then I press the button with id "input[class='btn']" // here i don't know use which property of the button to identify it ???

    Then I wait for 100 seconds

    Then I take a picture

Step definition is as bellow :
Then /^I enter "([^\"]*)" into input field with id "([^\"]*)"$/ do |text, css|


      performAction("set_text","WebView css:'input[text=\"TestWebView\"]'",text)



end



Then /^I press the button with id "([^\"]*)"$/ do |css|

      touch ("webView css:'input[contentDescription=\"More options\"]'")
end



Then /^I touch the button with id "([^\"]*)"$/ do | css|

  performAction('touch','css',css)

end



Then /^show the html source code$/ do

  performAction('dump_body_html')

end
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Execute `calabash-android console path_to/your_app.apk`;
2. Then execute `reinstall_apps`, then `start_test_server_in_background` and then `query "*"`

Comment: works when follow your way , and my question is how to work with my test app to let query output something ?

Comment: another , I remembered I have accept email notification ,but why there is not email send to me when you answer my question .  So i'm sorry for later reply .

Comment: when I input : calabash-android run testWebView.apk -v, the result is :"bonusInformation":[],"message":"",""success": true

Comment: `"bonusInformation":[],"message":"",""success": true` — is usually a result of `performAction` method. You should use `puts query("*")` instead of simple `query(*)` if you need to get output. By the way: it's hard to understand your code — many things are commented, others are not.

Comment: vote up need 15 reputation, and I have not enough reputation , and i'm sorry for click it by mistake to decrease it . For commented code, that I have tried for each of them .And all method don't work for me . My aim is to use query and performAction to implement my app. Currently, I can see query result , but I don't know which item is the textbox and which item is button .

Comment: And how to use performAction to input "test" into textbox and click the search button ?

Comment: Try `set_text "WebView css:'input[name=\"q\"]'", "test"` and then `touch "webView css:'input[class=\"btn\"]'"`.

Comment: Result is not displayed in comments.

Comment: BTW, for one of your previous answer: `"bonusInformation":[],"message":"",""success": true` means that performAction was successful.

Comment: I think you have working code already. In your original question... What do you expect to see in test run output?

Comment: i have multiple questions , thank you for your patient . And , the first question is : from the result of query , i want to know which lable or tag or item should be used to find the textbox and button . The result is different with HTML , from HTML , i see the textbox's  name is "q" , but i can't find "q" from results of query*; and from html , the button only with class property"btn" , and i can't find btn from query results as well. So i don't know why a lot of people use query to help them , what's its usage ?

Comment: If you have WebView, better to open its contents in mobile or desktop browser and find out locators there. I use web testing approach (e.g. Firebug, FirePath tools) for finding locators in WebViews and "query" command for finding locators for native elements.

Comment: Anyway, if you want to use `query` command for WebView elements, you should use `query "webview css:'*'"` instead of simple `query "*"` in order to browse HTML contents.

Comment: You mean query "*" is always used for client APP to find elements(such as app can installed on mobile phone) ? And for webview element you use Firebug, FirePath tools?

Comment: `query "*"` is for native elements. `query "webview css:'*'"` is for WebView elements. I use Firebug, FirePath and similar tools for WebViews because I'm used to them in web testing automation (Selenium WebDriver background) and they solve the same task more quickly for me.

Comment: Try `query "webview css:'*'"`.

Comment: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/wiki/06-webview-support is a short info on working with webviews from calabash-android documentation.

Comment: One more thing. Mobile app can include WebViews in it. Mobile apps are web, native and hybrid. Web apps are web applications itself, so WebView elements only. Native apps are native elements only. And hybrid apps have both of them. Calabash can automate all application types.

Comment: I have seen that doc , but at that time , I don't understand the argument clearly . Now I know its meaning , thank you Dmitry.

Comment: Though I don't understand what you say about native app and hybrid app. I will research it later . Things should do one by one , for I have lots of technology don't understand .  Now , the current thing , is I still can't pass the test .

Comment: Scenario: Test WebView

  Then I wait for 10 seconds

  Then I take a picture

  Then I enter "test" into input field with name "q" 

  Then I wait for 100 seconds

  Then I take a picture

  Then I press the button with class "btn" 

  Then I wait for 100 seconds

  Then I take a picture

Comment: Then /^I enter "([^\"]*)" into input field with id "([^\"]*)"$/ do |text, css|
      set_text "webView css:'input[name=\"q\"]'", "text"
 end

  

 Then /^I press the button with id "([^\"]*)"$/ do | css|
   touch "webView css:'input[class=\"btn\"]'"
 end

Comment: result is : 1 scenario(1 undefined)  8 steps(4 skipped, 2 undefined, 2 passed)

Comment: Yes, steps don't execute. "2 undefined" means steps in feature file don't match step definitions in rb file.

Comment: Dmitry, the test is passed only with a error  when execute "then I take a picture"  execution expired (httpclient:receiveTimeouterro).

Comment: Another , search from online , there seems a lot of method to input text to a textbox , such as keyboard_enter_text(text)  and performAction , could you tell me what's the difference ?

Comment: And could give me an example to use these two methods to my test app? So that ,I can understand the argument correctly and have a deep impression .

Comment: I have no time to look at this at the moment. Later.

Comment: `performAction` programatically assigns text to the field value; however `keyboard_enter_text(text)` emulates user behaviour - it really types text, character by character.

Comment: Theoretically (I haven't verified), `performAction` or `set_text` can set text for non-editable field. However `keyboard_enter_text(text)` will not allow to do this — the same way as end-user can't do that.

Comment: `keyboard_enter_text(text)` has specific usage: you should first set focus on the field — with `touch` method, for instance.

Comment: You can see examples of the usage of these both methods here: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8660/how-to-enter-text-in-the-usernamepassword-field-in-facebook-login-window-calab

Comment: And one more thing: `keyboard_enter_text` is available for iOS out-of-the-box, but for Android it should be defined additionally. See this post also: http://krazyrobot.com/2014/02/calabash-android-enter-text-from-keyboard-using-adb/

Comment: Thank you , I will look at them carefully and try to use them . Hope you can pay attention to my topic still. Another , could you mind give me another communicate method with you ?such as email or chat tools by phone?

Comment: i find an doc about usage of keyboard_enter_text method :

Comment: Usage tips

Tip 1:

In order for this to work your edit text field needs to be focused. You can achieve that by touching it – which usually also activates the soft keyboard. This means that you might need to get rid of it once you finished your input. Pressing the back key deactivates the keyboard:

touch("EditText id:'my_edit_text'")
keyboard_enter_text("I love calabash")
performAction('go_back')

Comment: Result when I use keyboard_enter_text : undefined method "keyboard_enter_text" for #(object:0x1e69bd0)

Comment: From the doc , I see it suggests not use keyboard_enter_text menthod in android . So ,i will try performAction .

Comment: `undefined method "keyboard_enter_text"` — because it's only in pre-release stage at the moment for calabash-android. But if you add its definition to rb file in your project, it will work.

Comment: So complex of this method , sign, I think I will not use this method afterwards.  Try performAction .  1) performAction("set_text","WebView css:''input[name=\"q\"]''",text)  # undefined set_text  2)default_device.performAction("set_text","WebView css:''input[name=\"q\"]''",text) # undefined method .

Comment: Does performAction is a common method to enter text to textbox ? or we random use it , but often use set_text ? is it enough for me to understand set_text only to input text to a text field ?

Comment: Dmitry ,  both of these following methods work fine . performAction("set_text",'css','input[name=q]', text) ; performAction("set_text",'webView css','input[name=q]', text) .

Comment: Current question is : I use performAction(list_actions) , I can see all actions can be used , but I don't know argument of them , and argument meaning , could you tell me when can find related things ?

Comment: I think `performAction` and `set_text` do the same. You can do any of them.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry , i now pass my first test project , and understand how mobile app automatic test works with cucumber and calabash.  Could you give me some suggestion on how to deep begin with it . i think i should study ruby and python language first . Right ?

Comment: Congratulations! ;) It's great. You can use built-in calabash steps, but they have several limitations. Ruby skills are great, and they will be useful for sure.

Comment: I've created chat for Calabash questions:
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15279/calabash

Comment: Build-in calabash steps? What are you mean? Do you mean the functions calabash-android or calabash-ios supported ? such as set_text , performActions?

Comment: Seems I have not enough reputation to chat there . Sigh .

Comment: Sorry, didn't knew that.

Comment: I mean these built-in steps: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/ruby-gem/lib/calabash-android/canned_steps.md

Comment: To those steps , we need some codes to implement it . such as function body, how to do it ? we have to use some script such as  ruby ? Right ?

Comment: You can use them in .feature files - where you write your scenarious. You've posted scenarios here, as I remember.

Comment: You can find links to few Calabash example projects here: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/8260/7941